# Jumpy transitions in d3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I have a force directed graph in d3 that I want to transition between multiple, overlapping datasets. I want the nodes to transition smoothly, but I've hit a wall in troubleshooting. I've tried to follow [Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0adcc447925ffae87975a3a81628a196) closely, but my nodes are jumping without any transition. I've made an example with exaggerated slow transitions to show what is going on. The nodes that remain in the graph immediately jump to their new locations and freeze while the simulation starts. Here is my [pen](https://codepen.io/brettasmi/pen/aKyGBv?editors=1011). Here is the relevant code:

```js
const cb = {"edges":[{"source":"a","target":"b","value":1},{"source":"a","target":"c","value":1},{"source":"b","target":"c","value":1},{"source":"c","target":"d","value":1},                   {"source":"d","target":"e","value":1},{"source":"d","target":"f","value":1},{"source":"g","target":"h","value":1},{"source":"a","target":"g","value":1}],"nodes":[{"id":"a","pop":12.00328963067508,"size":5},{"id":"b","pop":12.391087593534877,"size":5},{"id":"c","pop":12.384324067681156,"size":5},{"id":"d","pop":13.991090521661292,"size":6},
{"id":"e","pop":13.991090521661292,"size":6},
{"id":"f","pop":13.991090521661292,"size":6},
{"id":"g","pop":13.991090521661292,"size":6},{"id":"h","pop":13.991090521661292,"size":6}]}
const sp = {"edges":[{"source":"a","target":"b","value":1},{"source":"a","target":"e","value":1},{"source":"b","target":"f","value":1},{"source":"e","target":"f","value":1}],"nodes":[{"id":"a","pop":12.00328963067508,"size":5},{"id":"b","pop":12.391087593534877,"size":5},{"id":"e","pop":13.063656176168433,"size":6},{"id":"f","pop":12.52608275807238,"size":5}]}
// set margins and canvas size
const margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 30
};
const width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set up canvas
const svg = d3.select('.chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .call(responsivefy)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

// set up selections
let link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line");
let node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle");

// set up color scale
const color = d3.scaleSequential()
    .domain([8, 15])
    .interpolator(d3.interpolateInferno);

// set up simulation basic parameters
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

function render(graph) {
    // node selection and data handling
    node = node
        .data(graph.nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

    // node general update pattern
    node.exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("r", 0)
        .remove();
    node.transition().duration(1500)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
    node = node
        .enter().append("circle")
        .call(function(node) { 
            node.transition().duration(1500)
              .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.pop); })
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
        .merge(node);
  
    // give all nodes a title with their id for hover identification
    node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

    // link selection, data handling
    link = link
        .data(graph.edges, function(d) { return d.source + "-" + d.target; });

    // link general update pattern with attrTween to keep links connected to disappearing nodes
    link
        .exit()
        .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .attr("stroke-opacity", 0)
        .attr("stroke-width", 0)
        /* .attrTween("x1", function(d) {
            return function() {
                return d.source.x;
            };
        })
        .attrTween("x2", function(d) {
            return function() {
                return d.target.x;
            };
        })
        .attrTween("y1", function(d) {
            return function() {
                return d.source.y;
            };
        })
        .attrTween("y2", function(d) {
            return function() {
                return d.target.y;
            };
        }) */
        .remove();

    link = link
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
        .merge(link);

    // add nodes and links to the siumlation
    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);
    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.edges);
    // restart the simulation
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();

    // set the ticked function to constantly update node and link position
    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            });

        node
            .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });
    }
};

// initial render
render(cb)

// dragging functions
function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}

// responsivefy from https://brendansudol.com/writing/responsive-d3
function responsivefy(svg) {
    // get container + svg aspect ratio
    const container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode),
        width = parseInt(svg.style("width")),
        height = parseInt(svg.style("height")),
        aspect = width / height;

    // add viewBox and preserveAspectRatio properties,
    // and call resize so that svg resizes on inital page load
    svg.attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
        .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
        .call(resize);

    // to register multiple listeners for same event type,
    // you need to add namespace, i.e., 'click.foo'
    // necessary if you call invoke this function for multiple svgs
    // api docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on
    d3.select(window).on("resize." + container.attr("id"), resize);

    // get width of container and resize svg to fit it
    function resize() {
        const targetWidth = parseInt(container.style("width"));
        svg.attr("width", targetWidth);
        svg.attr("height", Math.round(targetWidth / aspect));
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Updating Graph</title>
<style>
.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick=render(sp)>render sp graph</button>
  <button onclick=render(cb)>render cb graph</button>
    <div class="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!